# Cannot get params over to rewrite url properly in Azure Api Management

Tags: azure-api-management

I'm trying to make apim take rewrite...

https://apimpath/customers/1234

to

https://backendpath/api/customers/1234

[image]

It fails. Tried a few things but they all don't seem to recognize customerId. What am i missing?

**------Update-------**

Tried some of the suggestions below and it didn't help. Here is the new ui showing the same message

[image]

Tried adding it through the api with several variations of this...

```
PUT {{url}}/apis/customers/operations/GET?api-version=2016-7-7
{
  "name": "GET",
  "method": "GET",
  "urlTemplate": "/{customerId}",
  "templateParameters": [
    {"name": "customerId", "type": "string"}
    ],
  "policies": null
}
```

Which added the operation successfully...

```
PUT {{url}}/apis/customers/operations/GET/policy/?api-version=2016-7-7
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base/>
        <rewrite-uri template="/api/customers/{customerId}"/>
    </inbound>
    <outbound>
        <base/>
    </outbound>
</policies>
```

But the request above failed with this result...

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ValidationError",
        "message": "One or more fields contain incorrect values:",
        "details": [
            {
                "code": "ValidationError",
                "target": "rewrite-uri",
                "message": "Error in element 'rewrite-uri' on line 4, column 10: Only parameters specified in the original URL template can be used in the rewrite template. Original template is: /*"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems strange.  It looks like what you are doing is correct.  Try setting the URL template, saving it and then setting the Rewrite URL Template as a second step.

Comment: Also, you might want to try and set it in the new UI in the Azure Portal.

Comment: Appreciate the suggestions but neither worked. Didn't know there was a new ui but if failed with the same error. Added that screenshot to the original question. Really stuck on this one.

Comment: Strange indeed. But all this UI does is just sets up a policy for you, so try to do it manuall: just save operation without rewrite template at all, head to policies section, select this operation in drop down list and add this to inbound section:

<rewrite-url template="/api/customers/{customerId}"/>

Let's see if this works.

Comment: Still the same issue. Removed the operation completely and readded it with no policy. Then added the policy in the old ui (in the policies section) and it failed as well. All the same error. Even tried this through the api, see updated question above, but same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug. I can recreate this as well.

If you create the operation with a parameter, this is saved somewhere.
Changing it doesn't seem to work, because

The correct order is to create the operation directly with the right parameter name. Then add the backend rewrite rule.

If you take a look at the screenshot, the original operation you created was "/*" and not "/{customerId}"

I tested this in the new UI/Portal.

- I created an operation "/{id}",
- Added the rewrite "/api/{id}"
- Tested it and it worked
- renamed the operation to "/{customerId}"
- encountered below error:

> One or more fields contain incorrect values:
>   Error in element 'rewrite-uri' on line 16, column 10: Only parameters specified in the original URL template can be used in the rewrite template. Original template is: /{id}

Comment: This issue is a bug in the apim system. Somehow, deleting an operation does not really delete the operation. You need to create a new operation with a new name or it still keeps the first url mapping and validates all policies against it. Thanks Erik!

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are saying that if you rename the URL Template for an operation and in doing so, change the template parameter name, it does not automatically update the corresponding template parameter in the RewriteUrl.  Is that right?

Comment: It will not be able to update parameter in rewrite-url because in general case there may be multiple and it's not clear which is which after rename. I've just tested that if you chage "/{id}" to "/{customerId}" in URL template AND change rewrite URL template to "/api/{customerId}" it works fine.

@sjdirect, are you still able to reproduce the issue?